# How can I raise my application's feed action request limit?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook

I'm trying to raise the limits for my application because after ~50 or so requests the app becomes non-functional. How can I do this?

This is the error:

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#341) Feed action request limit reached

Comment: You can't, all apps have this limit, it's very hard to have a policy compliant app that hits that limit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What @DMCS says is correct - there is an internal system at facebook that monitors user feedback - that means invites that users have declined, users that have blocked or hid your applications stories in their feeds, and possibly some sort of ratio between users that installed the application and removed it.

---

I was having trouble with these limits when I was developing the part of my application to do with user invites.  After testing the application by sending requests and accepting declining them quite a bit, I noticed some limitations being enforced - before my application even went live!

---

That was when I learnt about **sandbox mode** in the application settings panel.  When an application is in **sandbox mode** all the calculations and limitations are not enforced.  Now you can go about testing your invitation systems without worrying about beeing deemed a "bad" application.
 In addition only those users which you have granted access using the developers app role tab 
( `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/permissions` )
 will be able to see and use the application.  Another thing to note is that invites sent from an application in **sandbox mode** will not be received by users who have not been granted access.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook rates these limits on a per application level.  At F8 in 2009 people were asking about these limits and how they are being calculated, but everyone was shot down.  Their algorithm is very hush-hush.  The best way to get any limit raise is by being a good app, the way to get them lowered is from being a bad app.  Facebook uses a lot of user feedback to help them determine if you're being naughty or nice.