# Feed limit request reached - Facebook Android SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I know it's kind of repeated but I've looked here and others forums trying to find a reason to this error.
I've found the cause but I really would like to see the explanation in Facebook's API, and other informations for my app about the limits and the limit of time necessary to 'back to normal', but I  couldn't find it anywhere.

Do you know where can I find these informations directly on Facebook?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your app is in developing stage, you can turn on the sandbox mode (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8689443/92487). Also there a blog entry which mentions about the limit   https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2009/05/20/introducing-our-first-verified-apps/ check the 4th point.

Comment: Thanks, @Searock. Would you know where can we find information about the time that we have to wait until the limit back to zero? I've already read this time is 24hours, and in others posts is 48h. I'm confused.

Comment: There is no real official information about the limit. Also there are no fix timings and it differs by apps and over time depending on the app's behavior. Some say that this can be found at  Insights page(I codun't find it though). Please see facebook section at http://www.extly.com/autotweetng-documentation-faq/237-what-is-rate-limiting-errors-403-forbidden-and-341-feed-action-request-limit-reached.html