# Application request limit reached in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

In my Android App i am using facebook posts with photo. I am using the me/feed Request for this. It was working fine till yesterday. But unfortunately today morning onwared while trying to post i am getting the response as  as

```
uploadPhotoRequestCallback(14368): 
photo upload problem. 
Error={
HttpStatus: 500, 
errorCode: 341, 
errorType: FacebookApiException, 
errorMessage: Application request limit reached.
}
```

Anyone please help me to solve this problem

Comment: I am not sure about your code. Please try [this][1] if you can...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686954/how-can-i-raise-my-applications-feed-action-request-limit/8689443#8689443

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase the limit accorded by Facebook, you need to log/connect some users to your app. More users the app have and higher will be the limit/quota.

you can see the doc:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting?locale=en_GB#applimit